# other windows of same application get hidden when I close one of them

Tags: 11.10, unity, focus

I have several terminal windows open. they are all on top. Underneath them is, say, a browser window.
I close one terminal.
As a result, all the rest disappear (ie go out of sight) underneath the browser, which gains the focus.

I am using the latest 11.10 Unity with sloppy focus.

Closing one terminal should not lower all the others. It should leave me with the focus in the next highest terminal, if that previously had the focus before the one I closed.

Is this a bug?

Comment: One possible explanation: If you launched the second, third, etc., terminals from inside the first terminal, then they are child processes of the first terminal and will be shutdown when the first terminal is terminated.

Answer (score 1):

If the last window you used before the terminal you closed was Firefox, then it should get focus when you close that terminal. If it was another terminal, then that terminal should get focus. It is not clear from your question, but I hope this answered it in any case.

Comment: Wow, I don't think I was clear about my problem. The focus behaves fine.  But I have set things to "sloppy" focus, so I do not want window ordering/ visibility to change just because the focus does. This is only a problem in Unity.  When I close one console (the others are not children), my focus should go to the browser or another console, as appropriate, but which window is on top should not change.